# Combine counts with Group by from different tables to one result set

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have to find the daily  for last few days from 3 different tables, This is the query

```
    select CONVERT(Date,CompletedDate) as CompletedDate, count(ID) as Count
    from Table1 where CompletedDate >= DATEADD(day,-5, GetDate())
    group by CONVERT(Date,CompletedDate)

    select CONVERT(Date,CompletedDate) as CompletedDate, count(ID) as Count
    from Table2 where CompletedDate >= DATEADD(day,-5, GetDate())
    group by CONVERT(Date,CompletedDate)

    select CONVERT(Date,CompletedDate) as CompletedDate, count(ID) as Count
    from Table3 where CompletedDate >= DATEADD(day,-5, GetDate())
    group by CONVERT(Date,CompletedDate)
```

Is any way to sum the counts together for each day for a single day to a single dataset in a single SQL

Comment: You can `UNION ALL` them in a subquery, and do another aggregation in the outer query.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please try something like this .. If you are expecting something else please provide sample input and output.

```
select CompletedDate,SUM([Count]) cnt FROM 
(
    select CONVERT(Date,CompletedDate) as CompletedDate, count(ID) as Count
    from Table1 where CompletedDate >= DATEADD(day,-5, GetDate())
    group by CONVERT(Date,CompletedDate)
    UNION ALL
    select CONVERT(Date,CompletedDate) as CompletedDate, count(ID) as Count
    from Table2 where CompletedDate >= DATEADD(day,-5, GetDate())
    group by CONVERT(Date,CompletedDate)
    UNION ALL
    select CONVERT(Date,CompletedDate) as CompletedDate, count(ID) as Count
    from Table3 where CompletedDate >= DATEADD(day,-5, GetDate())
    group by CONVERT(Date,CompletedDate)
)x GROUP BY CompletedDate
```

Comment: Only one expression can be specified in the select list when the subquery is not introduced with EXISTS.
This is the error i am getting  while trying this . Also can you please cross-check the Group by syntax in the end of above query

Comment: You need to `SUM([Count])`. It is also advisable to choose a different alias than `Count`.

Comment: Yes SUM([Count]) is the perfect expression to be used